# What recessed shower light cover is this?

Tags: lighting, shower, recessed-lighting, light-fixture

We have a recessed shower light fixture and the cover is melted (thank you previous owners...). But I can't figure out what this thing is called or where I can get a replacement.

I've attached a few photos of the cover and the housing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: picture of the blue logo please - inside the light might help

Comment: The blue logo isn't a logo. It's one of those "warning" messages about getting shocked.

Comment: Did you ever find out what kind of cover it was (manufacturer or model number). I have one just like it and the plastic cover was also damaged by the light bulb.

Comment: @CactusThorn I'm afraid not. :(

Answer (score 1):

It's a recessed (canned) light cover (but I'm guessing you probably already knew that).

As "ppumkin" suggests in above comment, try to see if you can find a manufactures name (& model number) on the actual light fixture. Having such information to hand will greatly help you in tracking down an appropriate replacement cover.

Also you might want to check the bulb (Wattage & type) that is currently in there, as it really shouldn't have done such damage to the light cover.

Nowadays you can get compact fluorescent bulbs specifically for recessed lighting, or if money isn't an issue, look into available LED lights for use in recessed lighting.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I'm going to have to pull the whole fixture out to get that info. The blue text in the photo is just a warning message. The previous bulb that was in there was a 60 watt par bulb. Not sure if it's what did the damage though.